# Поток не завершает свою работу

Tags: android, kotlin, android-handler

У меня не очень большой опыт в многопоточности и поэтому я решил начать с теории и узнать, как Android обрабатывает в своем `mainThread` сторонние `thread`. И нашел вот эту [статью](http://javaway.info/mnogopotochnost-v-android-looper-handler-handlerthread-chast-1/)!

Попробовав перенести все это на практику, у меня получилось совсем не то, что я ожидал. Я ожидал, что во время выполнения программы будет всего лишь 2 `Toast` уведомления (то есть я думал до этого момента, что `Threads` по своей природе всегда конечный). Но на практике оказалось, что `Thread` не останавливается и я получаю множество `Toast` уведомлений.

Кто может мне объяснить почему мой поток не останавливается?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mUiHandler = Handler()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val task = Runnable {
            for (item: Int in 0 until 5){
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                if (item == 2)
                    mUiHandler.post { Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "I am at the middle of background task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
            }
            mUiHandler.post { Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Background task is completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
        }

        //Thread(task).start()
        val myWorkerThread = MyWorkerThread("Hello")
        myWorkerThread.apply {
            start()
            prepareHandler()
            postTask(task)
            //quit()
        }
    }

    class MyWorkerThread(nameT: String): HandlerThread(nameT){
        private lateinit var instance: Handler

        fun postTask(task: Runnable){
            instance.post(task)
        }

        fun prepareHandler(){
            instance = Handler(this.looper)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Все выглядит Ок с вашим кодом. Может активити несколько раз создается?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Да это маловероятно я запускал данный код на “голом” проекте. Очень интересно что Toas уведомления со временем появляются все чаще и чаще, перекрывая друг друга

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Да Вы были абсолютно правы, я пересоздавал Activity. Просто так получилось что данный проект я создавал что бы протестить новые функции android jetpack, а именно android jetpack navigation. И совсем забыл удалить с main_layout navGraph, и как всегда ошибка была в моей невнимательности :)